# JqueryMobile and Android 4.0 <a href="page1.html"... don´t work.

Tags: jquery, android, cordova

I have this code:

`$('#list').append('<li><a href="page1.html?id=1" data-transition="pop"><h3>Title</h3><p>Description</p></li>');`

It's working fine in Android 2.3.. but in Android 4.0.3 I get "error loading page".

I'm using phonegap 1.3 and jquery mobile.

page1.html is a local file in assets/www/page1.html

This is the Index.html code:

```
  <div data-role="page" id="idpage">
    <div data-role="header">           
        <h1>Tittle</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">       
      <ul id="list" data-role="listview" data-filter="false" data-filter-theme = "a" ></ul>                                   
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
      <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: What version of jQMobile are you using? I am using PhoneGap 1.5 with jQMobile 1.0.1 and page navigation works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug introduced in Honeycomb that persists into Ice Cream Sandwich where loading a file from the assets directory into a WebView will fail if the URI contains a query string or a fragment (#).

See this issue for more details: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535

One workaround is to copy the files to the app's internal storage directory and load them from there.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to use onclick event.